# Generating leads from website/blog

Tags: leads, web2lead

I need to connect my website/blog with Salesforce. The intention is to get leads when a user comes and registers via a registration form. Can anybody guide me on how to get it working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Web-to-Lead** function allows you to set up a form post to Salesforce to create new Lead records - [documentation](http://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_leadcapture.htm), [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2VNmg4F4ho).